Is there a reason, this specific SE site is unbearably slow?
When I open worldbuilding (and even meta) it is unbearably slow. Scolling is horrible, I can read faster than I can scoll. I have had this a few times now, every now and then I see an interesting hot topic or sidebar link from another SE site and come here. But then I just close the site and think "ah, I had something else to do anyway". But it's weird, why is this site special? Any other SE site is blazingly fast.
And there is nothing in either questions or answers, that isn't on other sites. I just tried to read a Q&A that had text, a few line header formats and maybe three links across all posts. That's nothing. No embedded formulas, no video, no spoiler tags that could hide lots of content. Nothing. Just plain formatted text.
Why is it that worldbuilding is so slow it's practically unusable, compared to all other SE sites who are perfectly fine at the exact same time?
Is there something in the theme that does background work?
I tagged this "bug", because I cannot use this site in the state it is in. I hope that "incredibly slow" is not the requirement for the site, but rather a deviation from it.

I am using latest Chrome on latest Windows, like probably the vast majority, nothing weird or exceptional.

Haven't experienced that. But I can't think of anything that would make this site any slower than others. Say, on Math.SE, there is the MathJax library which can slow down the loading of the page a bit. But it's not included here. This site should be otherwise hosted and served the same way as almost all other network sites. The only thing that might have any difference is that answers here tend to be longer. And if you visit something from the HNQ, it'd tend to have more answers. So, more content on the page overall. But I don't think it's an abnormal length.

Maybe worth checking: Do you happen to have any addons or userscripts that might influence the page? Can you try opening a page in incognito (assuming you haven't set your addons to run in Incognito. Just to simulate "clean profile")?

hm, interesting, that seems to have been it. I had an auto-comment addon for SE... but it wasn't allowed to read this site by default and I never changed that. Well, I dropped it and now it's fast, so I guess that was it. No idea why it would only slow one specific SE site to a crawl. Thanks!

Just for the Record

Simply because this is an interesting bug report, and because someone else might experience a similarly slow WB.SE session in the future, I think it worthwhile to copy the suggested problem & solution from comments.

VLAZ noted the following as potential issues:

Haven't experienced that. But I can't think of anything that would make this site any slower than others. Say, on Math.SE, there is the MathJax library which can slow down the loading of the page a bit. But it's not included here. This site should be otherwise hosted and served the same way as almost all other network sites. The only thing that might have any difference is that answers here tend to be longer. And if you visit something from the HNQ, it'd tend to have more answers. So, more content on the page overall. But I don't think it's an abnormal length.


And also:

Maybe worth checking: Do you happen to have any addons or userscripts that might influence the page? Can you try opening a page in incognito (assuming you haven't set your addons to run in Incognito. Just to simulate "clean profile")?


The OP checked into this suggestion and discovered that it was indeed the case:

hm, interesting, that seems to have been it. I had an auto-comment addon for SE... but it wasn't allowed to read this site by default and I never changed that. Well, I dropped it and now it's fast, so I guess that was it. No idea why it would only slow one specific SE site to a crawl. Thanks!

